# Чем лучше пользоваться XML или JSON?

Tags: xml, json

Вопрос чем лучше пользоваться?
В ajax я использую JSON  и честно говоря я не понимаю зачем тогда XML?
В чем глобальные отличия кроме построения???
Плюсы, минусы.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json

http://habrahabr.ru/post/31225/

Comment: обычным джейсоном ты не проверишь тип объекта, там нету схем и короче, читаем мат.часть.. =)

Comment: Чаще всего лучше использовать JSON, даже там, где, казалось-бы, без XML'я не обойтись, все-равно можно использовать JSON немного пораскинув мозгами.

Лично мое мнение о XML'е, как о формате - бездарность.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, почему бездарность?

Comment: @SingleAsen - избыточный синтаксис, как следствие, какие либо данные, представленные в XML - слабо-читаемое объемное месиво тегов.

К тому-же нет никаких правил построения такого рода документов, что приводит к еще более ужасным последствиям.

К тому-же, как таковой строгой типизации в XML нет, да, вы можете явно указать формат, но внимание вопрос - что вам мешает это сделать с JSON'ом?

Я бы мог продолжить, но, думаю, не стоит. На просторах гугла огромное множество качественной критик XML формата и его ущербности

Comment: @AlexWindHope, к сожалению, не могу согласиться. XML данные прекрасно читаются человеком, который способен читать и не является инвалидом...а вот про правила построения документов еще больше не согласен. См. [**Well-Formed XML Doc**][1]

[1]:http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp

Comment: @SingleAsen у вас уже сформировано "100% верное" мнение, не вижу смысла дальнейшей дискуссии, но, справедливости ради, замечу - не любой JSON валидный, к тому-же, синтаксические правила !== правило построения ( как я понимаю, различие вы не осилили ).

"который способен читать и не является инвалидом" Сразу видно - вы не имели дела с комплексным XML документом ( читай бредом )

Comment: > не могу согласиться. XML данные прекрасно читаются человеком

неправда. XML вообще нечитаем, теги и данные -- всё сливается.

> обычным джейсоном ты не проверишь тип объекта,

Смотря что понимать под типом. В отличие от XML в JSON есть встроенные float, int типы.

> там нету схем и короче, читаем мат.часть.. =)

Схемы есть, просто их описание ещё не вышло из черновика: [http://json-schema.org/](http://json-schema.org/)
Уже сейчас есть библиотеки которые умеют проверять соответсвие данных схеме.

Comment: @CostantinoRupert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json - страница не найдена же. Зачем приводите ссылку не рабочую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ранее ведь не было `JSON`, использовали `XML`, сейчас многие технологии так его и поддерживают для альтернативы, многие открытые `API` отдают информацию тоже в `XML`.
Вот вам статья по данному вопросу: [JSON и XML. Что лучше?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31225/).
Автор подробно рассказал про различия форматов `JSON` и `XML`.

UPD:
Со ссылкой опоздал..

Answer (score 3):

Работаю в поддержке банковкого ПО. Тут все на xml.
Для взаимодействия различных сервисов используется SOAP-протокол.
О переходе на JSON даже и мыслей нет.)))
Мое мнение, использовать то что отвечает задачам. Если видишь решение c JSON, делай с JSON. С этим проще работать на клиенте.
Если задача требует XML, юзай XML. Например, взаимодействие со стороней системой через SOAP.

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том, что так сложилось исторически. Формат XML был введен в оборот фирмой майкрософт и сразу они его стали пихать во все свои поделки. Причем, как вершину творческой мысли.
При все, казалось-бы, своей "универсальности", это очень неповоротливый в реализации работы с ним и очень избыточный формат. Поделка, которую мелкомягкие даже не удосужились, хоть как-то, нормально осмыслить и реализовать.
JSON - это более компактный и понятный формат.